# Using NPM install highest semver major version X

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Using package.json and NPM how can I install, using the command line, the highest number of major version 1 or major version 2?

In this case, I want to downgrade a package from version 2.x.x to 1.x.x. And this case, I want x to be the biggest number possible.

Something like:

```
npm install foo@latest:1
```

I am not sure. My end goal is to get the right data into package.json, such that I never jump to version 2.0.0, and always remain at the highest 1.x.x version.

Is there something I can manually insert into package.json? then run `npm install foo`?

Unfortunately [the NPM article on semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) is not helping much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wanting to always pick the latest and greatest for a particular version but not wanting to jump major version then you can use the `^` prefix in the package.json.

Example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^2.3.2"
  },
```

**Note:** The latest major release for nodemailer is version `4`.

This will resolves to `nodemailer@2.7.2`, which is the last release for version `2`.

Doing `npm install` produces the following

**Output:**

```
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.3.11: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
nodemailer@2.7.2 node_modules/nodemailer
```

**Reference:**
http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that manually:

```
npm install <package-name>@^xx
```

e.g. **npm install react@^18** will install the latest minor version of major version 18.